# How to respond to command line prompt using bat file (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am executing this in my .bat file via command line; inside of .bat is:

```
rmdir /S logs
```

Windows prompts:

```
logs, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

I have always to type Y. How do I make this automatic? I always want to respond Y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `help rmdir` you can add the parameter `/Q` to avoid the confirmation query.

Answer (score 3):

try this ->

<strike>`rmdir /S logs <y`</strike>

or

`echo y | rmdir /S logs`

or

`rmdir /S /Q logs`

taken from the help

`/Q      Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S`